# Android - Button's selector does not working when in toolbar

Tags: android, button, toolbar

I'm trying to set a selector to a button which included in a toolbar. The selector is working when it sets to a button outside to the toolbar. Any help?

**Toolbar**

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/light_red"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSync"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sync"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sinchronize_q" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sinchronize" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Do you see a ripple on touch of ImageButton?

Comment: Nope, cuz i'm testing it on a kitkat device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your drawable in particular this part

```
android:state_focused="true"
```

your ImageButton not getting focus because it is taken by its parent or some EditText view. In general *state_focused* used not quite often in drawables, 
change it to *state_pressed* and it will work so here is what you need

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sinchronize_q"
      android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/sinchronize"/>
```

if you want to make sure that your item was not getting focus you can add *android:focusableInTouchMode="true"* to your ImageButton